# adicionar itens de um loop while em uma ArrayList, Java

Tags: java

Preciso adicionar as entradas de um loop que o usuário fizer e armazenar em uma lista, do jeito que eu fiz está salvando somente o ultimo número, preciso que armazene todos.

System.out.println("Digite quantos pontos o cliente possui. ");
Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList bancoEntradas = new ArrayList();

```
                pontos = entrada1.nextInt();
                while (contador != pontos) {
                    System.out.println("Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos ");
                    System.out.println("Pontos em análise " + pontos + "  Somátorio dos pontos inseridos  " + contador);
                    Scanner entrada4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                    bancoEntradas.add(pontoinserido);
                   

                    while (pontoinserido != 3 && pontoinserido != 4 && pontoinserido != 5 && pontoinserido != 7) {

                        System.out.println("Resposta incorreta. Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos.");
                        pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                        if (pontoinserido < pontos) {
                            //pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                            continue;
                        }

                    }

                    contador = pontoinserido + contador;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pontos = entrada1.nextInt();
                while (contador != pontos) {
                    System.out.println("Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos ");
                    System.out.println("Pontos em análise " + pontos + "  Somátorio dos pontos inseridos  " + contador);
                    Scanner entrada4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                    bancoEntradas.add(pontoinserido);
                   

                    while (pontoinserido != 3 && pontoinserido != 4 && pontoinserido != 5 && pontoinserido != 7) {

                        System.out.println("Resposta incorreta. Digite as composição dos pontos, 3,4,5 ou 7 são permitidos.");
                        pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                        if (pontoinserido < pontos) {
                            //pontoinserido = entrada4.nextInt();
                            continue;
                        }

                        bancoEntradas.add(pontoinserido); // so faltou adicionar novamente na lista

                    }

                    contador = pontoinserido + contador;
```